# Form does not post JQ added input fields

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, dynamic

I have a html form

```
    <form action="/create" method="POST" class="form-group">

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="title">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row add-field-form ">
    <label for="pv" class="col-sm-12 form-control-label ">pv</label>
    <div class="entry input-group col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="pv" type="text" placeholder="Type something" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row add-field-form ">
    <label class="col-sm-12 form-control-label ">Options</label>
    <div class="entry input-group col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="options1title" name="options[1][title]" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In this form I am dynamiclly adding new inputs to both "pv" and "options".

The options will be like a sub object where it will have its own sub properties and I will need to post back an array of options with sub properties.

JS for dynamiclly adding new items :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = 1;
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    index++;

    var controlForm = $(this).parents('.add-field-form'),
      clonedEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first').clone(),
      newEntry = $(clonedEntry).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    newEntry.find('input').each(function() {
       var newName = $(this).attr('name').replace(/[0-9]/g, index);
       var newId = $(this).attr('id').replace(/[0-9]/g , index);
       $(this).attr('name', newName);
       $(this).attr('id', newId);
    });

    controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .btn-add')
      .removeClass('btn-add').addClass('btn-remove')
      .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
      .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>');
  }).on('click', '.btn-remove', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });


});
```

So when I add items to "pv" it does post back the array. When I add items to "options" it only posts back the original item(not the inputs added by JQ). I checked the network log and it is not being posted back.

I am guesssing there is not a problem with the html structure as , if I copy/paste the exact html produced by JQ to my original html file I am able post back the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears, for a form to be a valid HTML element it should have a block element. So I included a  global `<div>` inside `<form>` element and it started working.

My updated html looks like this :

```
<form action="/create" method="POST" class="form-group">
 <div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="title">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row add-field-form ">
    <label for="pv" class="col-sm-12 form-control-label ">pv</label>
    <div class="entry input-group col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="pv" type="text" placeholder="Type something" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row add-field-form ">
    <label class="col-sm-12 form-control-label ">Options</label>
    <div class="entry input-group col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="options1title" name="options[1][title]" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```